# Rails 4.1, Guard 2.10, and Minitest 5.4.1 -- RuntimeError & Rails::Generators::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, guard, minitest

I'm trying to set up Guard with Minitest in a new Rails 4 project. I updated my Gemfile with the following:

```
group :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end
```

And then ran `bundle exec guard init minitest`.

I've got a pretty simple test like so:

```
require 'test_helper'

describe ClassToBeTested do
  describe "#initialize" do
    it "should return a ClassToBeTested object" do
      obj = ClassToBeTested.new
      obj.must_be_kind_of ClassToBeTested
    end
  end
end
```

The class being tested is in `app/services/class_to_be_tested.rb`.

When I run `bundle exec guard -n f` I get the following:

```
11:35:43 - INFO - Guard::Minitest 2.3.2 is running, with Minitest::Unit 5.4.1!
11:35:43 - INFO - Running: all tests
Run options: --seed 36837

# Running:

E

Finished in 0.005190s, 192.6728 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
ClassToBeTested::#initialize#test_0001_should return a ClassToBeTested object:
RuntimeError: You need to configure your Rails::Generators::TestCase destination root.


1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
11:35:45 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/sean/Code/Ruby/work/project'
```

Is there something I'm missing? Something in Guard/Minitest/Rails that needs to be configured to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out -- apparently it thought that the class was a generator. Adding the following line to test_helper.rb inside the `class TestCase` block fixed the issue:

```
register_spec_type(/ClassToBeTested/, Minitest::Spec)
```

Is there a way to have all the classes in `test/services/` be subclassed under Minitest::Spec, and not the Generator test class?

Comment: What is the actual name of `ClassToBeTested`? Does it end in `Generator`?

Comment: ......maybe. It's `ThingGenerator`. If I switch it to `GenerateThings`, and not have to worry about the `register_spec_type` call?